# using MIN() and MAX() Function together

Tags: sql

Hello I am trying to solve a problem which requires use of MIN() and MAX()
Problem:

```
  ID   |    Date                 |    Field |    BP
1111111| 2020-08-12 07:10:00.000 | Systolic | 138 mm Hg
1111111| 2020-08-12 07:10:00.000 | Diastolic| 85 mm Hg
1111111| 2020-11-10 12:02:00.000 | Systolic | 153 mm Hg
1111111| 2020-11-10 12:02:00.000 | Diastolic| 87 mm Hg
1111111| 2020-11-10 12:03:00.000 | Systolic | 142 mm Hg
1111111| 2020-11-10 12:03:00.000 | Diastolic| 82 mm Hg
1111111| 2020-11-10 12:14:00.000 | Systolic | 132 mm Hg
1111111| 2020-11-10 12:14:00.000 | Diastolic| 84 mm Hg
2222222| 2020-11-12 08:51:00.000 | Systolic | 158 mm Hg
2222222| 2020-11-12 08:51:00.000 | Diastolic| 92 mm Hg
2222222| 2020-11-13 11:30:00.000 | Systolic | 140 mm Hg
2222222| 2020-11-13 11:30:00.000 | Diastolic| 85 mm Hg
```

Desired Output:

```
  ID   |    Date                 |   Field  |   BP
1111111| 2020-11-10 12:14:00.000 | Systolic | 132 mm Hg
1111111| 2020-11-10 12:03:00.000 | Diastolic| 82 mm Hg
2222222| 2020-11-13 11:30:00.000 | Systolic | 140 mm Hg
2222222| 2020-11-13 11:30:00.000 | Diastolic| 85 mm Hg
```

I am trying to write a query which would give me Maximum/Latest Date for each ID but at the same time MINIMUM/least value of the BP. So, for Each ID the query should give MAXIMUM DATE and MINIMUM BP Value.

There are two cases in the problem:
Case1: Some ID's have multiple BP values on the same date but at different time. So, in this case I desire to get the least BP value for Systolic and Diastolic for that Latest date irrespective of time.

Case 2: Some ID's have just one set of Systolic and Diastolic. So in this case too I desire to get the Least/minimum BP value for systolic and diastolic for the latest date irrespective of time.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery with aggregation:

```
select id, date, field, min(dp)
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id)
group by id, date, field;
```

Alternatively, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc, bp asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with window functions `MIN()` and `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
       FIRST_VALUE(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Field ORDER BY TRY_CAST(LEFT(BP, CHARINDEX(' ', BP) - 1) AS INTEGER)) Date,
       Field,
       CONCAT(MIN(TRY_CAST(LEFT(BP, CHARINDEX(' ', BP) - 1) AS INTEGER)) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Field), ' mm Hg') BP
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3c144fc977d8e431f4c9a1b247f2bc14).
Results:

```
>      ID | Date                    | Field     | BP       
> ------: | :---------------------- | :-------- | :--------
> 1111111 | 2020-11-10 12:03:00.000 | Diastolic | 82 mm Hg 
> 1111111 | 2020-11-10 12:14:00.000 | Systolic  | 132 mm Hg
> 2222222 | 2020-11-13 11:30:00.000 | Diastolic | 85 mm Hg 
> 2222222 | 2020-11-13 11:30:00.000 | Systolic  | 140 mm Hg
```

Comment: I am getting following error:  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '126 mm Hg' to data type int

Comment: @yogesh are you using SQL Server?

Comment: I am using SSMS for querying the data

Comment: @yogesh see my 2nd query.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working. I rna the query but I am not getting the desired output. I am just getting correct "max date" but the associated BP values are in correct. I am getting BP values from corresponding to different date under "Max Date"

Comment: @yogesh for the sample data that you posted the query returns the correct results. So maybe you did not explain clearly what you want or did not post sample data that includes special cases that are not covered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225372/discussion-between-yogesh-and-forpas).

Comment: I am sorry, if I was not able to explain it clearly. IS it possible for you to come on zoom and I can show you the data and the problem I am facing?
I am available on skype as well as webex. It will be a huge help if you could help me figure this problem out

Comment: No, you should edit your question and explain your requirement with sample data (not the same that you already posted) and expected results. This is how it works here in SO.

Comment: Hello Fopass thank you for being so patient with me. I have update the question and tried to be as clear as possible.